# Create empty output table with set number of rows with Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I know how I would do this with something like SAS, but if I wanted to create a table that had as many rows as there were month intervals derived from this statement:

```
cast((cast(2017-03-31 as date) - cast(2016-01-31 as date) month(4)) as int) as date_range
```

....to give an output like this:

```
2017-03-31
2017-02-28
2017-01-31
2017-12-31
2017-11-30
2017-10-31
2017-09-30
2017-08-31
2017-07-31
2017-06-30
2017-05-31
2017-04-30
```

What statement would I need to do this in Teradata?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just query the system calendar tables (views?).

Comment: What did you try?  Do you really want months into the future based on number of months in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those dates calulated based on existing columns?

Or do you just need that list?

In both cases you can utilze Teradata's proprietary `EXPAND ON` feature:

```
SELECT BEGIN(pd)
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR  -- your table here
WHERE calendar_date = DATE  -- EXPAND requires FROM, so this is just to get a single row
EXPAND ON PERIOD(date '2016-01-31'      -- start date
                ,date '2017-03-31' + 1  -- end date (+1 because it's not included in the date range)
                ) AS pd BY ANCHOR PERIOD MONTH_END -- one row for each month end within the period
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. i have still not decided how best to do it to be honest, but my values do need to come out of another dataset. i am not really sure how to apply the recursive logic in the example above to my scenario, as i am not 100% what the cte and the dte are supposed to represent...

Comment: @gdogg371: As Gordon wrote, `cte` is the alias of the recursive query and `dte` is the alias of the date column. If the data is coming from a table/result you better use EXPAND, the syntax is just not commonly use (most people don't know about it).

Comment: marked this as the correct answer as i got it working first, but i think they will both do what i need...the syntax for the 'with recursive' is a bit more foreign to me though, so will have to keep playing around with that. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is safer to get the first of the month because adding months to the last day of the month can be problematic (if you started with '2016-02-29' you would get the 29th of succeeding months).

You can do what you want with a recursive cte:

```
with recursive cte(dte) as (
        select cast('2016-02-01' as date)
        union all
        select add_months(cte.dte, 1)
        from cte
        where dte <= '2017-05-01'
    ),
    dates as (
        select dte - interval '1 day'
        from cte
    )
. . .
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. what do 'cte' and 'dte' represent in this example?

Comment: @gdogg371 . . . `cte` is the name of the recursive cte.  `dte` is the name of the date column for that `cte`.